# repeat the same aggregation on different columns in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, procedural-programming

I have a table like below:

```
product  |  weight   |  col1   |    col2   |   col3   | ...  |   col100
productA |  1        |  1      |    2      |   3      | ...  |   100
productB |  1        |  1      |    2      |   3      | ...  |   100
productA |  2        |  0.5    |    20     |   3      | ...  |   200
productB |  3        |  0.5    |    20     |   3      | ...  |   200
```

I want to write a query that calculates the weighted average of columns 1 to 100 using column weight for each product. The query is simple:

```
SELECT 
     product,
     SUM(weight*col1)/SUM(weight) OVER(partition by product) AS wighted_average_col1
FROM product_tbl
```

But I don't want to repeat the weighted average line 100 times for each column. Is there a way to create a loop here to iterate through the columns and create an output like below:
I have a table like below:

```
product  |  wighted_average_col1   |  wighted_average_col2   |    wighted_average_col3   ...  |   wighted_average_col100
productA |  0.33                   |  x                      |    y                           |   z
productB |  0.37                   |  n                      |    m                           |   l
```

Comment: use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE! there are plenty examples here on SO on how to dynamically build a sql for it

Comment: You need the query you have described with 100 tims about the same expression. But you can write a small app or use Excel to generate those lines for you.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant can you reference an example with the loop please. Thank you.

Comment: no loops involved in what I referenced! do some search for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE here on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74257394/5221944 is one of such examples to show technique, but you can find plenty

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Mikhail Berlyant, you can use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE!` to dynamically build a sql for it.

You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) for more information about executing a dynamic SQL statement.

You can also refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74257394/5221944) which is one of the examples for your requirement

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.